# Compress video FFMPEG doesn't work

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression

I'm trying to compress video using FFMPEG and this library: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

I imported ffmpeglib as a module in my project. This is the code is use to compress:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Object> listVideoPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getGalleryVideos();

        File videoFolderFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/");

        if(videoFolderFile.exists())
            Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "video folder exist");
        else
            Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "video folder DON'T exist");


        File videoInputFile = new File(listVideoPaths.get(0).toString());

        if(videoInputFile.exists())
            Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "video input file exist");
        else
            Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "video input file DON'T exist");

        File videoOutputFile = new File(videoFolderFile,"output.mp4");

        if(videoOutputFile.exists())
            Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "video output file exist");
        else
            Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "video output file DON'T exist");

        FfmpegController ffmpegController;

        try {
            ffmpegController = new FfmpegController(this,videoFolderFile);

            Clip mediaIn = new Clip();

            mediaIn.path = videoInputFile.getAbsolutePath();

            mediaIn.videoFps =  "25";

            ffmpegController.convertToMPEG(mediaIn, videoOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

                @Override
                public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                    Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "shellOut - " + shellLine);
                }

                @Override
                public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                    Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "proccess complete - " + exitValue);
                }
            });


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

            if(videoOutputFile.exists())
                Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "finished ffmpeg ---> video output file exist");
            else
                Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "finished ffmpeg ---> video output file DON'T exist");

        }
    }

    private void getGalleryVideos(){

        Cursor videoCursor = null;

        try {

            final String[] columns = { Media.DATA,
                    Media._ID,
                    Media.DATE_ADDED };

            final String orderBy = Media.DATE_ADDED;

            videoCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    null, null, orderBy);

            if (videoCursor != null && videoCursor.getCount() > 0) {

                while (videoCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    int dataColumnIndex = videoCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(Media.DATA);

                    listVideoPaths.add(videoCursor
                            .getString(dataColumnIndex));

                }

            }

            Collections.sort(listVideoPaths,new Comparator());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (videoCursor != null) {

                if (!videoCursor.isClosed()) {

                    videoCursor.close();

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I get no error but the video doesn't play. The log file is:

> 3096-3096/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   video folder exist 07-30 14:31:57.389
>   3096-3096/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   video input file exist 07-30 14:31:57.389
>   3096-3096/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   video output file DON'T exist 07-30 14:31:58.363
>   3096-3096/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -
>   /data/data/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste/app_bin/ffmpeg -y
>   -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150730_142330563.mp4 -f mpeg /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/output.mp4 07-30 14:31:58.385
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - WARNING: linker:
>   /data/data/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste/app_bin/ffmpeg has
>   text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security
>   hardening. Please fix. 07-30 14:31:58.390
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg
>   developers 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   built on Dec 22 2014 12:52:34 with gcc 4.6 20120106
>   (prerelease) 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8
>   --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/home/n8fr8/dev/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --sysroot=/home/n8fr8/dev/android/ndk/platforms/android-16/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIE -pie' --extra-ldflags='-L../x264 -fPIE -pie' --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100 07-30 14:31:58.391
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100 07-30 14:31:58.868
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150730_142330563.mp4': 07-30
>   14:31:58.869    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -   Metadata: 07-30 14:31:58.869
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     major_brand     : mp42 07-30 14:31:58.870
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     minor_version   : 0 07-30 14:31:58.871
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     compatible_brands: isommp42 07-30 14:31:58.872
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     creation_time   : 2015-07-30 17:23:34 07-30
>   14:31:58.873    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -   Duration: 00:00:01.89, start: 0.000000,
>   bitrate: 17571 kb/s 07-30 14:31:58.874
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 /
>   0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 15874 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9,
>   23.90 fps, 23.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc 07-30 14:31:58.875    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     Metadata: 07-30 14:31:58.876
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -       rotate          : 270 07-30 14:31:58.877
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -       creation_time   : 2015-07-30 17:23:34 07-30
>   14:31:58.878    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -       handler_name    : VideoHandle 07-30
>   14:31:58.878    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a /
>   0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s 07-30 14:31:58.878
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     Metadata: 07-30 14:31:58.878
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -       creation_time   : 2015-07-30 17:23:34 07-30
>   14:31:58.878    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -       handler_name    : SoundHandle 07-30
>   14:31:58.882    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut - [buffer @ 0xb5cce0a0] w:1920 h:1080
>   pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 sar:65536/65536 sws_param:flags=2 07-30
>   14:31:58.882    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut - [buffersink @ 0xb5cce0d0] No opaque field
>   provided 07-30 14:31:58.891
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - [mpeg @ 0xb5c3df00] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may
>   fail 07-30 14:31:58.892
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - Output #0, mpeg, to
>   '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/output.mp4': 07-30 14:31:58.894
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   Metadata: 07-30 14:31:58.895
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     major_brand     : mp42 07-30 14:31:58.896
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     minor_version   : 0 07-30 14:31:58.896
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     compatible_brands: isommp42 07-30 14:31:58.897
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     creation_time   : 2015-07-30 17:23:34 07-30
>   14:31:58.898    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -     encoder         : Lavf54.6.100 07-30
>   14:31:58.898    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg1video,
>   yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k
>   tbn, 23.98 tbc 07-30 14:31:58.899
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     Metadata: 07-30 14:31:58.899
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -       rotate          : 270 07-30 14:31:58.900
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -       creation_time   : 2015-07-30 17:23:34 07-30
>   14:31:58.901    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -       handler_name    : VideoHandle 07-30
>   14:31:58.906    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz,
>   stereo, s16, 128 kb/s 07-30 14:31:58.906
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -     Metadata: 07-30 14:31:58.906
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -       creation_time   : 2015-07-30 17:23:34 07-30
>   14:31:58.906    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -       handler_name    : SoundHandle 07-30
>   14:31:58.906    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut - Stream mapping: 07-30 14:31:58.906
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut -   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg1video) 07-30
>   14:31:58.906    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut -   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> mp2) 07-30
>   14:31:58.906    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut - Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 07-30
>   14:31:59.824    3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste
>   E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕ shellOut - frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=       0kB
>   time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s 07-30 14:32:02.029
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=    8 fps=2.7 q=10.5 size=       4kB time=00:00:00.25
>   bitrate= 130.9kbits/s 07-30 14:32:02.536
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   13 fps=3.7 q=25.2 size=     696kB time=00:00:00.45
>   bitrate=12427.3kbits/s 07-30 14:32:03.045
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   18 fps=4.4 q=31.0 size=     750kB time=00:00:00.66
>   bitrate=9206.8kbits/s 07-30 14:32:03.582
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   23 fps=5.0 q=31.0 size=     786kB time=00:00:00.87
>   bitrate=7351.4kbits/s 07-30 14:32:04.140
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   28 fps=5.5 q=31.0 size=     862kB time=00:00:01.08
>   bitrate=6511.8kbits/s 07-30 14:32:05.239
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   30 fps=4.8 q=31.0 size=     876kB time=00:00:01.16
>   bitrate=6144.9kbits/s 07-30 14:32:05.746
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   35 fps=5.2 q=31.0 size=     910kB time=00:00:01.37
>   bitrate=5416.2kbits/s 07-30 14:32:06.317
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   41 fps=5.6 q=31.0 size=     972kB time=00:00:01.62
>   bitrate=4895.2kbits/s 07-30 14:32:06.832
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - frame=   45 fps=5.7 q=31.0 Lsize=    1022kB
>   time=00:00:01.83 bitrate=4562.1kbits/s 07-30 14:32:06.832
>   3096-3182/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   shellOut - video:984kB audio:30kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead
>   0.756932% 07-30 14:32:06.858    3096-3096/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   proccess complete - 0 07-30 14:32:06.858
>   3096-3096/douglasanunciacao.androidffmpegjavateste E/TESTE FFMPEG﹕
>   terminou o ffmpeg ---> video output file exist

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded solving this problem by replacing this code:

```
    Clip mediaIn = new Clip();

            mediaIn.path = videoInputFile.getAbsolutePath();

            mediaIn.videoFps = "30";

            mediaIn.videoCodec = "mpeg4";

            mediaIn.width = 640;

            mediaIn.height = 352;

            mediaIn.videoBitrate = 1000;

//            "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150728_150045662.mp4 " +
//                    "-strict experimental -s 640x352 -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -ab 48000 " +
//                    "-ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 1000k /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/output2.mp4";

            ffmpegController.convertToMPEG(mediaIn, videoOutputFile.getAbsolutePath(), new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

                @Override
                public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                    Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "shellOut - " + shellLine);
                }

                @Override
                public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                    Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "proccess complete - " + exitValue);
                }
            });
```

By this code:

```
Clip clipIn = new Clip(videoInputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Clip clipOut = new Clip(videoOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            clipOut.videoCodec = "mpeg4";
            clipOut.videoFps = "30"; // tailor this to your needs
            clipOut.videoBitrate = 512; // 512 kbps - tailor this to your needs
            clipOut.audioChannels = 1;
            clipOut.width = 640;
            clipOut.height = 352;
            clipOut.duration = 2;
            ffmpegController.processVideo(clipIn, clipOut, true, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {
                @Override
                public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                    Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "shellOut - " + shellLine);
                }

                @Override
                public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                    Log.e("TEST FFMPEG", "proccess complete - " + exitValue);
                }
            });
```